# Thymeleaf setting model field with th:field on button dropdown not working

Tags: spring-mvc, model, thymeleaf, modelattribute

I am trying to set the field on my model object using thymeleaf in a form.
setting th:field on the button is giving back all null properties. They are all formatted the same but this is the look:

```
<div class="dropdown">
    <button th:field="*{product}" class="btn grey-dropdown dropdown-toggle" type="button"
    data-toggle="dropdown">(Select)<span class="caret"></span>
    </button>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu filter-dropdown-items">
            <li th:each="product : ${products}"><a><span 
th:text="${product}" th:remove="tag"></span></a></li>
        </ul>
</div>
```

Am I doing something wrong? The post comes back with null fields.

Comment: Can't you use native html option selector instead of <ul> and <li> ?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can tell, [`th:field` only supports the following tags](https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/3.0/thymeleafspring.html#inputs):

- input
- select
- textarea

If you want to bind a button, I think you're going to have to do it manually. (`th:field` sets the `name`, `id`, and `value` attributes so it shouldn't be difficult to set them to the correct values.)